# Loading indicator re-shown in my fragments when replacing them from Navigation drawer item in the Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer

I have multiple fragments witch I replace in my Activity included a Navigation Drawer :

```
private fun setupNavigationView() {
        binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
            val fragment = when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.action_movies -> {
                    viewModel.setType(R.string.menu_movies, NavType.MOVIES)
                    feedMovieFragment
                }
                R.id.action_tv_series -> {
                    viewModel.setType(R.string.menu_tv_series, NavType.TV_SERIES)
                    feedTVShowFragment

                }
                R.id.action_setting -> {
                    viewModel.setType(R.string.menu_setting, NavType.SETTING)
                    settingFragment

                }
                else -> throw RuntimeException("Unknown item to replace fragment")
            }
            invalidateOptionsMenu()
            replaceFragmentInActivity(fragment, R.id.fragment_container)
            true
        }
    }
```

Fragments initialized once in the Activity :

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var feedMovieFragment: FeedMovieFragment

    @Inject
    lateinit var feedTVShowFragment: FeedTVShowFragment
```

The Fragments are extending a base fragment which is a ComposeView :

```
abstract class FeedFragment<T : TmdbItem> : BaseNavigationFragment<Nothing>() {

    protected abstract val viewModel: FeedViewModel<T>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = composeView {
        TmdbTheme {
            Content(viewModel) {
                FeedCollectionList(
                    navType,
                    it
                ) { tmdbItem ->
                    startDetailActivity(tmdbItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a child fragment sample :

```
class FeedMovieFragment @Inject
constructor() // Required empty public constructor
    : FeedFragment<Movie>() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: FeedMovieViewModel.Factory

    override val viewModel
        get() = ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[FeedMovieViewModel::class.java]

    override val navType: NavType
        get() = NavType.MOVIES
}
```

The problem is every time I click on a navigation drawer item, it shows loading indicator and then displaying items. My expectation is when loading indicator showed once, it should not be re-shown since I initialize fragment once and reuse the same fragment.

Here is Content composable method :

```
@Composable
fun <T> Content(
    viewModel: BaseViewModel<T>,
    successScreen: @Composable (T) -> Unit
) {
    when (val resource = viewModel.stateFlow.collectAsState().value) {
        is Resource.Loading -> ProgressScreen()
        is Resource.Success -> successScreen(resource.data)
        is Resource.Error -> ErrorScreen(
            message = resource.message, refresh = viewModel::refresh
        )
    }
}
```

Even if I scrolled to end of the list, the second time I click on navigation drawer item, it shows end of the list and not re-shown from top but loading indicator shows at start.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Here is BaseViewModel :

```
open class BaseViewModel<T>(
    private val repository: BaseRepository<T>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _stateFlow = MutableStateFlow<Resource<T>>(Resource.Loading)
    val stateFlow: StateFlow<Resource<T>>
        get() = _stateFlow.asStateFlow()

    init {
        refresh()
    }

    fun refresh() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.result.collect {
                _stateFlow.tryEmit(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Addenda :** There is a hacky way :

```
private var feeds: List<FeedWrapper<T>>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return composeView {
            TmdbTheme {
                if (feeds == null) {
                    Content(viewModel) {
                        feeds = it
                        FeedCollectionScreen()
                    }
                } else {
                    FeedCollectionScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't like this solution because when we rotate the device `feeds` list becomes null again. But is there a better solution?

Source code can be found here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Paging-Playground